# FPDF: MultiCell does not accept bullet points

Tags: python, unicode, fpdf

When using the *windows-1252* encoding (only this works for me), I can display bullet points like `u"\u2022"` in cells, but when I put a bullet point into MultiCell, it throws an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x95' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_doc_option("core_fonts_encoding", "windows-1252")
pdf.set_font("Times", size=14)
pdf.cell(w=0, h=6, txt="\u2022 This outputs correctly", ln=2)
pdf.multi_cell(w=0, h=6, txt="\u2022 This raises an error", ln=2)
```

How can I fix it?
I use Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8.5.

Comment: Do you mean *windows-1252* encoding?  AFAIK, _FPDF for Python_ supports Unicode (`utf-8`) quite well… Please [edit] the question and share a (sanitized) [mcve].

Comment: If you try to encode `"\u2022"`, but you get an encode error about `"\x95"`, then it looks like something is going wrong. I can reproduce the exception with the following (useless) round-trip encoding: `'\u2022'.encode('cp1252').decode('latin1').encode('cp1252')`.

Comment: UTF-8 does not show bullet points (do not know, why!)

Comment: Added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: â€¢ that's what I get using UTF-8. It shows 3 different bytes.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your MWE: first, I needed to `pdf.add_page()` before the call to `.cell()`, then this latter call resulted in an `AttributeError` because of a library access to `self.unifontsub`... After reading your examples, scrolling through the FAQs of fpdf.org and seeing snippets of the code in the traceback, I got the impression that some unhealthy assumptions about encoding are built into this library.

Comment: After finding the docs, I learned that your MWE also lacks the `pdf.set_font()` call. This is vital information for your question, because this call sets up encoding, it seems. Have you read [these instructions](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Unicode/index.html) about using Unicode outside the Latin-1 range?

Comment: Now I can reproduce your problem. Please, next time start your question in a shape like this up-front. – To me, it looks like a bug. Unfortunately, the project looks abandoned, but maybe you're lucky and someone fixed it in one of the [many open pull requests](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/pulls)...